# What happens to an if statement not followed by curly braces?

Tags: c#, if-statement, curly-braces

I am trying to understand this code snippet:

```
class Worker
{
    public bool DoThisJob(string job, int numberOfShifts)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentJob))
            return false;
        for (int i = 0; i < jobsICanDo.Length; i++)
            if (jobsICanDo[i] == job)
            {
                currentJob = job;
                this.shiftsToWork = numberOfShifts;
                shiftsWorked = 0;
                return true;
            }
        return false;
    }
}
```

If this `if` statement has more then one line of code (including the `for` loop and the two `return`s), why doesn't it have curly braces?

Comment: This if does not have more than one line of code. And even if it did, it would return anyway.

Comment: I don't really understand why people are downvoting this.

Comment: @Jonesy: Me eather, I upvoted when it was down to I think -4? It's a simple question, but still valid.

Answer (score 9):

The code is equivalent to this:

```
class Worker
{
    public bool DoThisJob(string job, int numberOfShifts)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentJob))
        {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < jobsICanDo.Length; i++)
        {
            if (jobsICanDo[i] == job)
            {
                currentJob = job;
                this.shiftsToWork = numberOfShifts;
                shiftsWorked = 0;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Only the next statement is part of the if when there are no curly brackets. For the `for` loop, the `if` is the next statement, so everything is included with it.

Answer (score 6):

The `if` statement only has one line of code.  The bottom `return false`; is outside of that if statement.

Comment: This is also a good example of why a lot of people recommend you always include the curly braces, even if your `if` statement only has a single line of code.

Comment: Nah. Not necessary. Waste of time adding unused braces. And some of us lazier programmers hate the added clutter.

Comment: @jacknad No lol. It's bad practice not to add curly braces even for one line. At least in the C#/javascript world. I agree with what you said in theory, but in the real world where other developers touch your code and (yes they should know as well) it just adds more confusion. Just add the curly brackets. I would even say if you have an if/else that BOTH have one line of code then that's fine, but if you have an if statement without curly and and else/else if with them it's confusing to look at.

Answer (score 5):

> if this IF Statement has more then one line of code

It doesn't.  The body of the first `if` statement is only: `return false;`.  The rest of it is after the end of the `if` body.

Answer (score 4):

If there aren't any curly brackets with the If statement, just one statement will be considered under the If statement.

In this example, only one statment will be executed: "return false;"

Answer (score 3):

In C# curly braces are optional, but only for the first line of code.

Meaning that if the statement does not have braces, only the line of code right after the if condition (the statement body) will be executed. Everything else falls outside the statement body and therefore will not be executed.

Same works with if else:

```
if(SomeCompare())
return false;
else
return true;
```

Answer (score 2):

this is the same as:

```
public bool DoThisJob(string job, int numberOfShifts)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentJob))
    {
      return false;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < jobsICanDo.Length; i++)
            if (jobsICanDo[i] == job)
            {
                currentJob = job;
                this.shiftsToWork = numberOfShifts;
                shiftsWorked = 0;
                return true;
            }
        return false;
    }
}
```

the else simply isnt needed, because it won't get executed due to the return, if the if statement evaluates to true

Comment: Note: The rest of the the method is in the else only because the first `if` will exit the funtion with the `return false;` statement. Otherwise the `for` loop would still be executed even if the first `if` was true.

Answer (score 1):

That `IF` Statement has not more than one line of code. If other codes was for that `IF` statement, they never execute because the code always returns false at the very first line after the `IF`.